# Is there any Open Source alternative to e-paper CMS?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

I'm looking for an open source CMS such as

- [Express News](http://www.express.com.pk/epaper/)
- [Dawn E-Paper](http://epaper.dawn.com)

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580582/epaper-application) has already been asked but its still without a proper answer.

Comment: it can't be there!

Comment: Do you mean I have to write one myself?